# Issues with drawing a table using rowspan and colspan using HTML

Tags: html, firefox, html-table, microsoft-edge

I have started to draw a table in HTML. I desired to draw [image]

Observe that 2.2 starts at center of 1.1 and 3.1 starts at center of 2.2. 
The code I wrote for this is

```html
<table border="3" width="400" height="200">
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">1.1</td>
  <td>1.2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">2.2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3.1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">4.1</td>
 </tr>
<table>
```

You can see the output. Can any one tell me why the output is not as i desired by suggesting the changes in the code. Thanks in advance.

**After going through the comments I found that code is working fine in chrome. Problem is only in Firefox and Edge.**

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data, not layout.

Comment: <tr> default: float left , so 2.2 float to right side then not enough for 3.1 float at left side

Comment: You want to center the text inside the table?

Comment: @Kollein Can you please eloborate

Comment: @Fil Not worried about position of text. Only the structure of table.

Comment: so what formatting you need? can you further explain?

Comment: See the structure of table . 2.2 starts at center of 1.1 and 3.1 starts at center of 2.2

Comment: Could this be a browser issue? For me, in Chrome the table is rendered as desired, in Firefox it is not.

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer  Yes I think so. Because my answer is same as desired one according to my view

Comment: @Pawan, your code works fine on chrome. Please edit your question for particular browser and tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to specify cell height in order to get this work.

```css
table {
    text-align:center;
    border-collapse:collapse;
  }
```

```html
<table border="3" width="400" height="200">
 <tr>
  <td height="40"  rowspan="2">1.1</td>
  <td>1.2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">2.2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3.1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">4.1</td>
 </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Does not looks like OP request

Answer (score 0):

use border-collapse: collapse; to table style
try this code

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }

td{
  text-align:center;
  
  }
```

```html
<table border="3" width="500" height="300">
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">1.1</td>
  <td>1.2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">2.2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3.1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">4.1</td>
 </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: OP is not asking about borders or text align.

Comment: It's clear that your table is not same design as OP image

Comment: there is no difference between them in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this style

```
<style media="screen">
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .center {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

and your code for table,

```
<table width="400" height="200">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
      <div class="center"> 1.1 </div>
    </td>
        <td>
      <div class="center"> 1.2 </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
      <div class="center"> 2.2 </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
      <div class="center"> 3.1 </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
      <div class="center"> 4.1 </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is written fine for rowspans, check this if it helps

```
<table border="3" width="400" height="200">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">1.1</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>        
        <td rowspan="3">2.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: none;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">4.1</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```